# Oracle persistent connections maxing out server from asyncronous PHP scripts

Tags: php, oracle, persistence, oracle-call-interface

I have written a simple OCI wrapper class in PHP which uses persistent connections (`oci_pconnect`). The class destructor calls `oci_close`.

This class is used for all my AJAX PHP scripts and so is called a lot. However, despite using persistent connections and `oci_close` not removing these from the cache (as per my understanding), the number of open connections to the database is maxing out, causing the system to fail. I was expecting the number of open connections to be just one for the whole app!

Am I doing something obviously wrong?

---

Skeleton code:

```
class Oracle {
  private $connection;
  private $connected;

  function __construct($connectionString, $username, $password) {
    if (!($this->connection = @oci_pconnect($username, $password, $connectionString))) {
      echo 'Cannot connect to '.$username.'@'.$connectionString;
      $this->connected = false;
    } else {
      $this->connected = true;
    }
  }

  function __destruct() {
    if ($this->connected) {
      oci_close($this->connection);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I experienced the same problem with an inherited system. drop oci_pconnect in favour of oci_connect (non-persistent)

Comment: It solved the problem, so never found out why connections weren't being re-used.

Comment: Whilst this would solve the problem, it makes the system quite noticeably slower.

Comment: Are all your connections using the same username, password, and connection string?

Comment: @BobJarvis Yep, they all connect to the same schema on the same SID

Comment: My only suggestion is to echo the username and connection string after a successful connection so you can eyeball it.  Other than that I'm short on ideas.

Comment: One other thing - add an echo in __destruct so you can eyeball-verify that oci_close is being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do NOT close the connection if you want it to be persistent.

Comment: From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-close.php): "The `oci_close()` function does not close the underlying database connections created with `oci_pconnect()`."... Does `oci_close` therefore not work as documented?

Comment: That's probably outdated. `oci_close()` does close persistent connections since PHP 5.3.

Comment: @Xophmeister Depending on your setting and PHP version, `oci_close` may be able to close `oci_pconnect()`: [PHP Doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/oci8.configuration.php#ini.oci8.persistent-timeout)

Comment: I'm using PHP 5.2.17, but `oci8.persistent_timeout = -1`, so presumably then `oci_close` *is* closing the connections... Can anyone confirm?

Comment: Can't confirm, but two things: 1) the behavior of your system seems to indicate this is not the case - or at least indicates that the underlying database connection is not being closed, and 2) it's simple enough to test - comment out the oci_close call and see what happens.

Comment: According to the [doc page](http://php.net/manual/en/oci8.configuration.php), "Setting this option to -1 means that idle persistent connections will be retained until the PHP process terminates or the connection is explicitly closed with oci_close()".  So if this is set to -1 it would seem you'd need to call oci_close to make the connection available for reuse.

Comment: On a second thought ... do you have HTTP/1.1 and keep-alive turned on?

Comment: Yes: HTTP/1.1 and keep-alive. (With regards to experimenting: I don't have access to the DB server's logs, so can't directly test how code changes affect the system.)